# Get Index of MKAnnotation in MapView.annotations Array

Tags: ios, xcode, indexing, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am making an App in xCode with an MKMapView and MKAnnotations. If you make more than two annotations the extra waypoints colors (PinAnnotations) should be changed to purple.

Therefore **I need something like a tag, IndexPath or ID from the annotation** to identify the MKAnnotation in the MKAnnotation functions. I used this line of code:

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;

    if (annotation != mkMap.userLocation)
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"aPin";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mkMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        if (pinView == nil)
        {
            pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

            pinView.tag = mapView.annotations.count;    // tag is not available for annotation in this function
        }
    }

    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    pinView.draggable = YES;


    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return pinView;

    NSLog(@"Annotation-Index: %d", [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:annotation]);
    NSLog(@"MapView.annotations.count = %d", mapView.annotations.count);

    if (1 == [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:annotation])
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    else if (1 < [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:annotation])
    {

        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

        // checkes for extra waypoints
        if (2 < mapView.annotations.count)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i > mapView.annotations.count; i++)
            {
                MKPinAnnotationView *aView = [mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i];
                aView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

                [mapView removeAnnotation:mapView.annotations[i]];
                NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [a replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:aView];

                [mapView addAnnotations:a];
            }
        }
    }

    return pinView;
}
```

I already google this question and found a number of solutions like I did

```
int AnnotationIndex = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:annotation];
```

but the the output of this function (Annotation-Index) strikes my mind. Sometimes everything is fine but and the Annotation-Index has the right value but most of the time the values seems to be generated randomly and the scale goes from 0 up to 10 also if the MapView.annotations.count is just 3!

Best regards and thanks!

Comment: You can probably print out the titles of the annotations to have a better understanding of what happens. (title of `view.annotation` and those of all `mapView.annotations`)

Comment: You are aware that, your code only insert the annotation on the array, when user click on it?

From Apple docs:
mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:
Tells the delegate that the user tapped one of the annotation view’s accessory buttons.

Comment: sorry guys I entered a wrong example and noticed it too late but now I edited it... but you are right I will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way of handling this is to make your own class that implements the MKAnnotation protocol and has a property that you can check during `viewForAnnotations` to see what colour to use. The `annotations` array from MKMapView is not guaranteed to be in the order in which you add annotations to the map. You may add annoy, annoy and then annoy but you may get back [anno2, anno3, anno1]. That's just the way it is and you can't change that. So, you could keep your own array of annotations that won't get rearranged. Or use the extra property idea if that will suit.

One thing you should not do is add more annotations during the `viewForAnnotation` function, that's really messed up.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! 
If there is someone like me who had problems with the Custom MKAnnotation class - here a link (its pretty easy):
http://blog.flatironschool.com/post/64218319803/creating-custom-map-annotations-using-mkannotation